# How to access to remote Postgresql database in django

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

Greeting.

My simple project was set for local Mysql database but my client required that the database should be Postgresql on AWS.
He sent me the url and Access key pair.
The information he sent are following.
https://0387XXXXXX98.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
User name: "xxxxx"
Password:""  # he did not send password
Access key ID: "AKIXXXXXXXXXXXMAA"
Secret access key: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Please help me to migrate my project. I am not familar with AWS.
What I want to know is
 1. How to access to AWS Postgresql instance.
 2. How can I set up my project for remote AWS Postgresql with above information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I put the information again.

- https://0387XXXXXX98.signin.aws.amazon.com/console
- User name: "xxxxx"
- Password:""   # (he did not send password)
- Access key ID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
- Secret access key: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the postgre database, you need to have the:

- database endpoint ( which you can get from the console ),
- port,
- database name,
- username,
- password
- List item

Use any of Python drivers for PostgreSQL ( Psycopg2 /pg8000 / any other) and connect to the database.

It could be like as follows:

```
import psycopg2 as driv # this could be pg8000
conn = driv.connect(database='DB', user='USER', password='Qwerty123!', host='mycluster.cluster-123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', port='3306')
```